# Destroying a Linked list in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

So here's my code for destroying a linked list.

```
void destroy(node *h){
    if (h->next!=NULL){
        destroy(h->next);
    }
    free(h);
    h=NULL;

}
```

The problem is that printing still outputs a bunch of numbers:

> 11, 2, 15, 3, 9, //Before Destroy
>
> 28495936, 28495968, 28496064, 28496096, 0, //After Destroy

Unfortunately I cannot alter the `void destroy(node *h)` parameters due to assignment reasons.
I've tried using a while loop method but I still get the same result. I've also tried shifting to the left and deleting from the end but then I wouldn't be able to delete the last node.

thanks in advance.

--edit--- 
as requested, here is the print function

```
void print(node* N){
        printf("%d, ", N->value);
    if (N->next)
        print_set(N->next);
    if (N == NULL)
        printf("Empty Set");
}
```

Comment: Can we see the code you're using to print the list ?

Comment: Why would you print a list you destroyed ? If the assignment is the prototype `void destroy(node*)` then you can't change the pointer in the function calling `destroy()`, so you won't be able to have the pointer become null to prevent printing.

Comment: I've added my code for printing.

Comment: Put the NULL check before printing anything. Eg.,
void print( node* N ) 
{ if( N == NULL ) {printf("NULL\t"); return;} // Rest printing code here }

Comment: @Abhineet good thinking, but still the same result. It's not detecting N as NULL

Comment: That was not the solution. It was just a mere advice :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `h=null` in your function does not do anything. You're modifying a local parameter so it won't have any effect outside the function.

Thus, the only thing you do is freeing the memory, but you keep the address the same. Your list still exists, pointing to random memory location (well not random : the same as before, but the values at this memory locations are random)

When you print your list after that (which is strange because you're supposed to have destroyed it... Why would you want to print it again ?), you print random values in memory.

This is a problem because your program could also crash (you're accessing memory which is not allocated).

The solution, unfortunately, requires to change the signature of your function :

```
void destroy(node **h){
    if ((*h)->next!=NULL){
        destroy((*h)->next);
    }
    free(*h);
    *h=NULL;

}
```

If you can't, you have to set the pointer to NULL after destroying it, like this:

```
void destroy(node *h){
    if (h->next!=NULL){
        destroy(h->next);
        h->next=NULL;
    }
    free(h);
}
```

and in the calling function:

```
destroy(myList);
myList=NULL;
```

Comment: that works.I'm not sure I can set myList=NULL in my main method that's the problem..

Comment: I don't see any other way to ensure that you don't use a destroyed list. Since the memory is freed, keeping the pointer is useless, and not setting in to NULL keeps the risk to use it again later in the code, which would cause your application to crash (or a behavior similar to what you asked about in this question).

Comment: It seems there is no other way given the circumstances. I'll ask my lecturer. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 3):

You must set `h->next = NULL`. Also, after the call to `destroy`, make sure you don't use the pointer anymore because it is freed. So, always after `destroy(n)`, make sure that you have `n = NULL`.

A better way is probably to change the signature to `void destroy(node **h)`, so the code becomes:

```
void destroy(node **h){
    if ((*h)->next!=NULL){
        destroy(&h->next);
    }
    free(*h);
    *h=NULL;
}
```

Then you ensures that you are not using the pointer afterwards.

In your `print` function, you must add this check at the beginning:

```
if(N == NULL) return;
```

Comment: that surely did help, however when I print I'm getting one number printed:

`11, 2, 15, 3, 9, 
//after
11886656,`

Comment: @PatrickBuhagiar: That's because your `print` function contained a mistake. You must check for `NULL` already at the beginning (because it is `NULL` and thus invalid to use). I extended my answer.

Comment: @PatrickBuhagiar: Which platform are you on, using which compiler?

Comment: Due to assignment reasons, I cannot pass `(node **h)` as a parameter :(

Comment: @alk Ubuntu 13.04 and Linux gcc

Answer (score 3):

If the [solution provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19489655/694576) by *[Albert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133374/albert)* is not possible due to some rules, the only possibility **you as the author** of the source in  question have is to **remember the list's nodes had been deallocated** and therefore contain invalid references to memory and that the code you write because of the latter **may not dereference such pointers**, that is they may not be passed to the printing functions as this would provoke undefined behaviour by accessing un/deallocated memory.

If writing such potential insecure code, it is in your responsibilty as the author to use it carefully and document it very well for your fellow programmers maintaining the code after you left the project.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably in code you haven't posted!

I assume you keep a 'head' pointer to your list, and your code looks like this.

```
Node * myList;

.. do stuff..

destroy(myList);
print(myList);
```

The problem is that you don't set `myList = NULL` following the destroy.

```
destroy(myList);
myList = NULL;
print(myList);
```

Your `h=NULL` in `destroy()` doesn't do anything because it's modifying a local parameter.

Comment: In which case you need to pass a *pointer* to myList - see @Albert's solution (including fixing `print()`. Note also that recursion is not a recommended way to traverse a list!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your structure looks like, but I'm guessing something like this:

```
struct {
  int something;
  int* value;
  list* next;
}
```

The problem is that even though `h` is the NULL pointer, `h->value` and `h->next` are not. They are pointers in `NULL+1` and `NULL+2`, which may point to random places in memory.

Comment: my struct consists of an int value and a next pointer. how should I go about it? I mean, I can't set h->value to NULL..

Answer (score 1):

Try this code if u are working on singly linked list

```
void destroy(node *h){    
   node *n;    
   node *p; \\ variable to store previous term
   n=h;
   while(n->next!=NULL){
   p = n;
 }
  p->next=NULL;  
   free(n);
```

}

Comment: This code is to delete one term(last term) for the list at a time.